# Java generate this simple int[][] serie

Tags: algorithm

I'm doing simple a exercise with Java, I need to generate this series in an int[16][16] array, but I don't see the algorithm and the logic..

- 1
- 1    1
- 1    2    1
- 1    3    3    1
- 1    4    6    4    1
- 1    5   10   10    5    1
- 1    6   15   20   15    6    1
- 1    7   21   35   35   21    7     1
- 1    8   28   56   70   56    28    8    1
- 1    9   36   84  126  126    84   36    9    1
- 1   10   45  120  210  252   210  120   45   10    1
- 1   11   55  165  330  462   462  330  165   55   11    1

Anyone see the logic..?

Answer (score 2):

Each number is the sum of the one just above and its neighbour on its left.

```
val[i][j]=val[i-1][j]+val[i-1][j-1]
```

if a value does not exist, assume 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1
1 11 55 165 330 462 462 330 165 55 11 1


1 (1+11) (11+55) (55+165) .................. 1
```

To get a number in the next row you have to build the sum of the number in the same column in the row before and the number in the column-1 in the previous row.